# Using Raster Calculator in QGIS produces output with strange values

Tags: statistics, calculator, raster, qgis

I am adding a number of raster grids together using the Raster Calculator in QGIS, but my output file displays very large values in the range on the layer Legend e.g. 340,282,346,638,528,859,811,704,183,484,516,925,440 to
-340,282,346,638,528,859,811,704,183,484,516,925,440
(please see the image attached).
[raster range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdhA0.png)

The raster grids that I am using are all Float32. This file also displays no information in the summary statistics.

Any ideas how I can avoid this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it helped to select a layer (I used one of the rasters I used for the calculation) before opening the raster calculator. The coordinate-system should be correct, as well as the layer extend. DO NOT click on 'use selected layer extend'. You can continue with your normal calculation.